# Refreshing only specified div after X seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is there a way how can I refresh only a specified div every X seconds?
Code is here just for nice formatting, I dont think its useful for you guys.

```
<div class='live-upgrades' id='iWantToRefreshThis><p>LATEST UPGRADES<hr></p>
        <div class='liveupgradesscroll'>
            <div style='position:relative;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:5px;left:40px;' align='left'>"; echo "$nick"; $nick = $nicknames_array[array_rand($nicknames_array)]; echo "</div>                       
            <div style='display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #161616;'>
                <img src='"; print("$degrade"); $randomde = (mt_rand()%$totalde); $degrade = "$degrade_array[$randomde]";   echo "' align='left' />
                <img src='img/spacer.png' />
                <img src='"; print("$upgrade"); $randomup = (mt_rand()%$totalup); $upgrade = "$upgrade_array[$randomup]";  echo "' align='right' />
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at how and why you should separate HTML, script and PHP. It will improve your code and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: You will need AJAX. But what about the code here? There are many errors in it; does it actually work?

Comment: Code is working, very good. Code is here just for nice formatting as I said.

Comment: Every code I found on internet has '.load('response.php')'
I dont need that tho, so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
     //This Is Main File (index.php or any name)

    <div class='live-upgrades' id='iWantToRefreshThis'><p>LATEST UPGRADES<hr></p></div>

        <script src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
        function Refresh(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "query.php",
                    //data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                    $("#iWantToRefreshThis").html(html);
                    }
                    });
                };
            $(window).bind("load", function() {  
            setInterval( function() {
                        Refresh(); 
                        },1000); //time limit for refreshing your data

            });
        </script>


//Make Another Page And Call That Page By AJAX Call With URL mentioned in AJAX Script

//query.php //which will show refeshed data here i'm showing for a random number


<div class='liveupgradesscroll'>
                    Hello I Am Your Random Number <?php echo rand();?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use This , Hope it will work for you , and don't forget to add jquery for calling ajax .

Comment: ughhh, I dont get it. Should I put code I want to refresh in query.php only or what exactly?

Comment: i am putting a working demo here , that will work for you :)

Comment: I dont kinda understand this, what should be placed in Query.php exactly?
When I put <div class='liveupgradesscroll'> ..... </div> in query.php, nothin' is happening on my site

Comment: I've re-edited that code and its working on my server :)